# Fetch data from Table using sequelizejs in Node.js

Tags: node.js, postgresql, orm, sequelize.js

I am new in node.js, i want to fetch the data from table of the postgresql using sequelize ORM in node.js. I am using below code but its not working.

```
  const apisListModel = sequelize.define('apisList', {});
  apisListModel.findAll().then((data)=>{
              JSON.stringify(data,undefined,2);
            },(e)=>{
                console.log(e);

             });
```

Its give me error

```
        Executing (default): SELECT "id", "createdAt", "updatedAt" FROM 
           "apisLists" AS "apisList";
      { SequelizeDatabaseError: relation "apisLists" does not exist
```

But apiList table exist in my DATABASE

Answer (score 0):

Sequelize changes the tableName to plural implicitly. You can define options as

```
const apisListModel = sequelize.define('apisList', {}, {
  tableName: 'apisList'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The query trying to fetch data from `apisLists` but your table name is `apiList`. Note the "s" in table name.

If this is the case, you can specify the table name using the option

`tableName: 'apiList'`

Here is the [Documentation link](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-definition.html#configuration)